# SSH Config: Force ipv4 connections to travel via a jump host

Tags: ssh

SSH connections via ivp4 are running unstable due to a ISP level CGNAT implementation.

If there was an easy way to specify a PATTERN in my SSH config to match on all IPV4 hosts then I could set this to then use an ipv6 jump host?

Alternatively there might be an alternative way to set this up?